# SUM of paired columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Iam having TableInput

```
    A B AB ID H  I 
    1 1 1-1 3 1 2.2   //CASE1
    1 1 1-1 3 2 3.4   //CASE1
    1 4 1-4 3 1 2.2   
    1 4 1-4 3 4 4.2 
    1 4 1-4 3 4 3.2 
    1 5 1-5 3 4 1.2 
    1 5 1-5 3 4 3.2 
    1 6 1-6 3 4 5.2
```

Here consider CASE1 where AB column is having value of 1-1,finding the same pair 1-1 in other rows and must add columns values in H .

There fore my result table must be like..

```
      A B AB SUM(H) SUM(I) 
      1 1 1-1  3     5.6 
      1 4 1-4  9     9.6 
      1 5 1-5  8     2.4 
      1 6 1-6  4     5.2
```

Not getting idea of how to query for my output table..

Can any one please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
SELECT A, B, AB, 
       SUM(H) AS SumH,
       SUM(I) AS SumI
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY A, B, AB
```

You have to apply [aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) on columns that you want to select that are not part of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thnaks this is wokring

Answer (score 1):

```
  Select A,B,AB, 
   SUM(H) as [SUM(H)],
    SUM(I) as [SUM(I)] 
  FROM Table1
     GROUP BY A, B, AB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(A), MAX(B), AB, MAX(ID), SUM(H), SUM(I)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY AB
```

**Result:**

[image]